# integral operator with degenerate kernel

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I have an integral operator on $L^2$, $\int_0^1K(s,t)f(t)dt$ where K(s,t) is degenerate. Can I state that the norm of this operator equals its largest eigenvalue absolute value?
As a concrete example, I'd like to find the norm when $K(s,t)=\cos(s+t)=\cos(s)\cos(t)-\sin(s)\sin(t) $

Comment: Your operator reduces to the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$. And $\|Af\|^{2}=(A^{T}Af,f) \le \lambda(f,f)=\lambda\|f\|^{2}$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,
$$
K(s,t) = \overline{K(t,s)}
$$
so the corresponding integral operator $T_K$ is self-adjoint. Thus, the norm of $T_K$ coincides with its spectral radius. Now since the spectrum is compact, $\exists 0\neq \lambda \in \sigma(T_K)$ such that $|\lambda| = \|T_K\|$. Since $T_K$ is a compact operator and $\lambda\neq 0$, $\lambda$ must be an eigen-value of $T_K$.